# How to solve a hard integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How prove $ \displaystyle \int _{ 0 }^{ \infty }{ (1+x)\arctan { (x) }  } \log^4 { (x) }{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}(1+x^2)}}   dx=\frac{57\pi^6\sqrt{2}}{64}  $

I found this integral using numerical values.I think the result is correct!
How to prove this result?

Comment: A preliminary substitution you could try is $x=\tan t$ but I have no idea if it's the correct approach.

Comment: It might work: replace $x$ with $\tan\theta$ then compute a couple of Fourier series and pray you are able to integrate their product.

Comment: It looks like a tough integral but it is a nice one.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Okay, I'm going to do this the "special functions and pray" way: the first thing to do is produce a simpler integral; the one I'm going to deal with is
$$ I(a,s) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{s-1}}{1+x^2} \arctan{\sqrt{a} x} \, dx. $$
(Another option is using $\arctan{(a+x)}$, but that looked even worse when I tried it.)

Now, the required integral is
$$ \left. \frac{\partial^4}{\partial s^4} (I(1,s)+I(1,s+1)) \right|_{s=1/2} \tag{1}; $$
store that away and concentrate on $I$. Now, I don't know about you, but I'm still not convinced I know how to do $I$ directly, so begin with $\partial I/\partial a$, which is
$$ \frac{\partial I}{\partial a} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{a}}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{s-1}}{1+x^2} \frac{x}{1+a x^2} \, dx; $$
this one we can do using partial fractions or contour integration, for example, in the usual way, giving
$$ \frac{\partial I}{\partial a} = \frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{a}} \frac{1-a^{(1-s)/2}}{1-a} \sec{\tfrac{1}{2}\pi s}. \tag{2} $$
At this point we see there's going to be trouble at $ a=1 $. So now we need to compute $I(1,s)$; it is apparent that $I(0,s)=0$, so we can compute $ I(1,s) = \int_0^1 \frac{\partial I(a,s)}{\partial a} \, da $. At this point it would be reasonable to worry: the function we have to integrate is, well, a bit weird. Therefore it is at this point that special functions enter the fray: one [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Integral_representations) of the digamma function is:
$$ \psi(\alpha+1) = -\gamma + \int_0^1 \frac{1-y^{\alpha}}{1-y} \, dy. $$
This isn't quite what we've got, but we can write
$$ \frac{1-a^{(1-s)/2}}{(1-a)a^{1/2}} = \frac{1-a^{1/2}}{(1-a)a^{1/2}} + \frac{1-a^{-s/2}}{1-a} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}(1+\sqrt{a})} + \frac{1-a^{-s/2}}{1-a}. $$
The second of these obviously gives our digamma, and the first integrates to $\log{4}$ by elementary means. Therefore we have made it as far as
$$ I(1,s) = \frac{\pi}{4} \left( \gamma + \log{4} + \psi\left(1-\tfrac{1}{2}s\right) \right)\sec{\tfrac{1}{2}\pi s}, $$
and now we just have to take the four derivatives and evaluate them.

Thankfully at this point another trick suggests itself: $I(1,s)+I(1,2-s)$ has the same $0,2,4,\dotsc$th derivatives at $s=1/2$ as $I(1,s)+I(1,1+s)$. Therefore we can take this sum:
$$ \begin{align*}
I(1,s)+I(1,2-s) &= \frac{\pi}{4} \left( \gamma + \log{4} + \psi\left(1-\tfrac{1}{2}s\right) \right)\sec{\tfrac{1}{2}\pi s} + \frac{\pi}{4} \left( \gamma + \log{4} + \psi\left(1-\tfrac{1}{2}(2-s)\right) \right)\sec{\tfrac{1}{2}\pi(2- s)} \\
&= \frac{\pi}{4} \left( \psi\left(1-\tfrac{1}{2}s\right) - \psi\left(\tfrac{1}{2}s\right) \right) \sec{\tfrac{1}{2}\pi s} \\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{4} \csc{\tfrac{1}{2}\pi s},
\end{align*}
$$
using the [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Reflection_formula). It is now straightforward to find fourth derivative at $s=1/2$; it is indeed
$$ \left. \frac{\partial^4}{\partial s^4} (I(1,s)+I(1,s+1)) \right|_{s=1/2} = \frac{57\pi^6\sqrt{2}}{64}. $$

---

**Edited to add:**

I didn't actually have to get my digamma on (I just felt like evaluating $I(1,s)$, in the end). Instead, look at (2), and do the same trick with sending $s \mapsto 2-s$. Then the sum becomes
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial a} (I(a,s)+I(a,2-s) ) = \frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{a}} \left( \frac{1-a^{(1-s)/2}}{1-a} \sec{\tfrac{1}{2}\pi s} + \frac{1-a^{(s-1)/2}}{1-a} \sec{\tfrac{1}{2}\pi (2-s)} \right) \\
= \frac{\pi}{4} \frac{a^{s/2-1}-a^{-s/2}}{1-a} \sec{\tfrac{1}{2}\pi s}
$$
The fraction may look a little familiar to some: integrating from $0$ to $1$, we find
$$ I(a,s)+I(a,2-s) = \frac{\pi}{4} \sec{\tfrac{1}{2}\pi s} \int_0^1  \frac{a^{s/2-1}-a^{-s/2}}{1-a} \, da. $$
The integral is most easily computed by expanding $(1-a)^{-1}$ as a power series and integrating term-by-term, from which we obtain
$$ \int_0^1  \frac{a^{s/2-1}-a^{-s/2}}{1-a} \, da = \pi \cot{\tfrac{1}{2}\pi s}, $$
(see [here](http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/311/cotan.pdf) for a derivation) (You could also change variables on the second term and consider it as a principal value integral), and then proceed as before. (Remarkably, this makes evaluating the integral all-but elementary: we only need the cotangent series and differentiation under the integral sign).

---

**Edited again:**

I think what @Francois Jaclot's answer is getting at is that the function
$$ \frac{x^{1/2}+1/x^{1/2}}{x+1/x}(\log{x})^4 $$
is invariant under the transformation $x \mapsto 1/x$, and
$$ \arctan{x} + \arctan{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)} = \frac{\pi}{2}. $$
The integration operator $ \int_1^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x} $ maps to $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x} $. It follows that, calling the integral we want $I$,
$$ I = \int_0^{1} \frac{x^{1/2}+1/x^{1/2}}{x+1/x}(\log{x})^4 \arctan{x} \frac{dx}{x} +  \int_0^{1} \frac{x^{1/2}+1/x^{1/2}}{x+1/x}(\log{x})^4 \arctan{\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)} \frac{dx}{x} \\
= \frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^{1} \frac{x^{1/2}+x^{-1/2}}{1+x^2}(\log{x})^4 \, \frac{dx}{x}
$$
Substituting $y=x^2$, $dy/y = 2dx/x$, so
$$ I = \frac{\pi}{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 16} \int_0^{1} \frac{y^{1/4}+y^{-1/4}}{1+y} (\log{y})^4 \frac{dy}{y}.  $$
Applying the transformation $y \mapsto 1/y$ again, we can rewrite the $y^{-1/4}$ term as an integral on $[1,\infty)$, ending up with:
$$\begin{align*}
I &= \frac{\pi}{64} \left( \int_0^{1} \frac{y^{1/4}}{1+y} (\log{y})^4 \frac{dy}{y} + \int_1^{\infty} \frac{y^{1/4}}{1+y} (\log{y})^4 \frac{dy}{y}. \right) \\
&= \frac{\pi}{64} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{y^{-3/4}}{1+y} (\log{y})^4 dy \\
&= \frac{\pi}{64} \left. \frac{d^4}{ds^4}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{y^{s-1}}{1+y} \, dy \right|_{s=1/4} \\
&= \frac{\pi}{64} \left. \frac{d^4}{ds^4} \pi \csc{\pi s} \right|_{s=1/4}
\end{align*}, $$
giving the answer again. (I don't like this method as much: all this $1/x$ transforming is quite tricky to get right...)

Comment: This is a fantastic answer +1

Comment: Chappers is legit +1

Comment: (+1) "Special functions and pray" is now the name for a wonderful technique.

Comment: Wonderful, very nice demonstration.Thanks(+1)

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way, considering $\arctan(x)$ can be easily eliminated. Hence the integral becomes $1/32$th of the fourth derivative of Beta$(t, 1-t)$ at $t = 1/4$.

Comment: Maybe you should expand this answer with some more details?